# Add a repo to GitHub Desktop from command line

Tags: github-desktop

Is it possible to add a new repo to GitHub Desktop's repo list from a command line API of some sort?

Searching has largely led to results about adding a repo to GitHub via command line, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can open GitHub Desktop with any Git repo just by passing it as a parameter on the command line:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0\path\to\Github.exe \path\to\repo
```

This will open the application with the repo added and selected.  I doubt there is a way to add the repo without actually opening the application.